# How to save products to custom text file?

Tags: magento

I need to save a custom text file on server which contain all products. I tried to search any plugin for this but not found.

Comment: What do you mean with that "product"? Simple export with ID, Name, Sku  etc to CSV file, or everything (including images etc.)?

Comment: everything, + product link, product image link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a module where I added a mass action to the product grid with event/observer. I will not add here the whole module code but the code for the export would be something like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

//write headers to the csv file
$content = "ID,Name,SKU,SomeOtherStuff\r\n";

foreach ($products as $_product) {
    $product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

    $content .= "\"{$product->getId()}\",\"{$product->getName()}\",\"{$product->getSku()}\",\"{$product->getSomeOtherStuff()}\"\n";
}

$this->_prepareDownloadResponse('Products.csv', $content, 'text/csv');
```

For the images you will have to add something to the code: `$product->getMediaGalleryImages()`, `$product->getImageUrl()` (you will need `addAttributeToSelect('image')` in the collection for this) or as you wish.